# Android dotted line issue

Tags: android, user-interface, lag

In my application I use dotted lines as list item dividers in Navigation Drawer and in main screen. However when I launch application on device and see the main list with desired divider I'm happy but when I try to open Navigation Drawer the whole thing starts to lag a lot.

Have anyone else experienced this? Do you have something to suggest as a viable solution?

Thanks!

Update: activity layout sample code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/contentLv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/dotted_line"
            android:layerType="software"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/navDrawerBg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/globalNav_lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/dotted_line"
            android:layerType="software"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I did cut the irrelevant parts of the code but to give you some idea will let you know that the adapters of `ListView` aren't that fancy and aren't performance hungry. The lag wasn't there before I've added both `android:layerType="software"`

Comment: How do you know it's the dotted line? Also what sort of resource is this, a normal image or an XML based drawable?

Comment: To answer your questions. When I have only one dotted line set I see the expected result on screen. The resource is an XML based, if needed I can add the code for that as well